# Cordova.writefile function doesn't run, but doesn't give an error

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I'm making an ionic application. I have a function called scope.win() that's supposed to fire when a quiz is finished, and then update the JSON file to add that quiz to the number of finished quizzes but it doesn't run properly.It doesn't give off any error. The function just stops running at a certain point and the app keeps going and nothing is happening.
This is the controller's file

```
    angular.module('controllers', ['services'])

 .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $state, data) {
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function () {
    data.create();

});
$scope.chapter = data.chapterProgress();



 })
 .controller("BtnClick", function ($scope, lives, data, $cordovaFile, $ionicScrollDelegate) {
var live = 3;
var clickedOn = [];
var numQuestions;
$scope.part2Cred = false;
$scope.part3Cred = false;
$scope.part4Cred = false;
$scope.part5Cred = false;
$scope.part6Cred = false;
$scope.part7Cred = false;
$scope.part8Cred = false;
$scope.part9Cred = false;
$scope.part10Cred = false;
$scope.partQCred = false;

$scope.setNumQuestions = function(num){
    numQuestions = num;
}

$scope.updatelives = function (){
    //grabs the element that is called liv then updates it
    var livesOnPage = document.getElementById('liv');
    livesOnPage.innerHTML = live;
}
$scope.wrong = function (event){
    var selec = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    if(clickedOn.includes(selec)){}
    else{
        selec.style.color = "grey";
        clickedOn.push(selec);
        live = live - 1;
        if(live == 0){
            $scope.gameover();
        }
        else{
            $scope.updatelives();
        }
    }
}
$scope.right = function (event,chapter, section){
    var selec = document.getElementById(event.target.id);
    if(clickedOn.includes(selec)){}
    else{
        selec.style.color = "green";
        clickedOn.push(selec);
        numQuestions = numQuestions - 1;
        if(numQuestions === 0){


            $scope.win(chapter, section);


        }
    }
}
$scope.gameover = function(){
    alert("game over please try again");
    live = 3;
    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
    $scope.partQCred = false;
    $scope.part1Cred = !$scope.part1Cred;
    for(i = 0; i< clickedOn.length;i++){
        clickedOn[i].style.color = "rgb(68,68,68)";
    }

}
$scope.win = function (chapter, section) {
    alert("Well Done");
    var data = data.chapterProgress(); // It is at this point that the //function stops running without giving off any error.
    alert("Good Job");
    var sectionsComplete = data[chapter].sectionsCompleted;
    var totalsection = data[chapter].totalSections;

    if (section === totalSection) {
        window.location.href = "#/chapter1sections";
        return;
    }
    if (section > sectionsComplete) {
        data[chapter].sectionsCompleted += 1;
        var url = "";
        if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
            url = "/android_asset/www/";
        }

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            $cordovaFile.writeFile(url + "js/", "chapters.json", data, true)
      .then(function (success) {
          // success
          alert("Json file updated")
          window.location.href = "#/chapter1sections";
      }, function (error) {
          // error

      });
        });
    }
}



});
```

Here is the Services file. It seems to run fine but it is referenced a lot in the problematic sections of code in the controllers so I figured it was necessary to put it here.

```
    angular.module('services', [])
.service('lives', function () {
    var live = 3;

    return {
        getlives: function () {
            return live;
        },
        setlives: function (value) {
            live = value;
        }
    };
})
.service('data', function ($cordovaFile, $http) {
    var url = "";
    if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
        url = "/android_asset/www/";
    }
    return {
        //Run this function on startup to check if the chapters.json file exists, if not, then it will be created
        create: function () {
            var init = {
                "one": {
                    "sectionsCompleted": 0,
                    "totalSections": 4
                },
                "two": {
                    "sectionsCompleted": 0,
                    "totalSections": 1
                }
            };

            $cordovaFile.writeFile(url + "js/", "chapters.json", init, false)
  .then(function (success) {
      // success

  }, function (error) {
      // error

  });

        },

        chapterProgress: function () {
           return $http.get(url + "js/chapters.json").success(function (response) {
                var json = JSON.parse(response);
                return json;
            }, function (error) {
                alert(error);
            });
    }

    }
});
```

Thank You so much for the help and time.

Comment: Which platform are you targeting? windows, android or iOS? And could you please post the related html codes?

Comment: We plan to target Android and IOS however right now we're just focusing on Android.